# onoff switch input type checkbox onclick is not working (it doesnt call the function) how should i call that function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I have an MVC5 project that has a list of campaigns and each campaign has a toggle switch, I can't call the function `sss()`. Here is the code:

```
<div class="switch">
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    @if (item.IsActive)
    {
      <input type="checkbox" checked
             class="onoffswitch-checkbox"
             onclick="sss(this)" data-camid="@item.id">
    } else {
      <input type="checkbox"
             class="onoffswitch-checkbox"
             onclick="sss(this)" data-camid="@item.id">
    }
    <label class="onoffswitch-label">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Javascript part:

```
<script>
  function sss(elem) {
    var cid = $(elem).data('camid');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCampaignMer", "Merchant")',
      data: {
        campaignId: cid
      },
      success: function(res) {
        $(button).parents("tr").remove();
        $("body").mLoading('hide');
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

but when I put a button instead of checkbox input, it works fine:

```
<button onclick="sss(this)" data-camid="@item.id">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem, it was the structure of the switch

```
<div class="switch">
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    @if (item.IsActive)
    {
      <input type="checkbox" checked
             class="onoffswitch-checkbox" onclick="sss(this)"
             data-camid="@item.id" id="@item.id">
    } else {
      <input type="checkbox"
             class="onoffswitch-checkbox" onclick="sss(this)"
             data-camid="@item.id" id="@item.id">
    }
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="@item.id" style="margin-bottom: -5px;">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

We have to put an `id` for each input and the same `id` as a `for` in each label, to show which label is for which input so it can be clickable.

Thank you @Jerdine Sabio for helping me.